# Comparing file created yesterday with file created today

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have files in a directory  as shown in the below format.

$today and $yesterday are two variables holding today's date and yesterday's date , both will hold date as shown in below structure .
today=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d')

```sh
example-$today.txt
polar-$today.txt
example-$yesteday.txt
polar-$yesteday.txt
```

> Example yesterday : example-2020-09-24.txt
> Example today: example-2020-09-25.txt

Files are created on a daily basis using cronjob , so there will be files in below structure with tomorrow's date.

```sh
example-$tomorrow.txt
polar-$tomorrow.txt
```

I want to compare files starting with same name on different dates and if there is difference execute a python script.The python script takes today's file as first argument if there is a difference.

```sh
if diff example-$today.txt example-$yesteday.txt
then 
echo "No difference"
else
python script.py example-$today.txt
fi
```

If I have only 2 or 3 files I can use if else code for each file using diff as mentioned above, but the list will be populated with more unique names in future , and writing if command is tedious.

Requirement :

Compare all the txt files in the directory with same named file names on yesterday and today , if there is a difference execute the python script.

Comment: What if there is a missing day? What do you want the script to do? compare 2020-01-01 with 2020-01-03 if 02 is missing, or do nothing?

Comment: Please write one Exact Filename Example. Is it example-2020-01-01.txt ? something else?

Comment: @thanasisp I have updated the question with exact file name example

Comment: nice, please check the first comment, what to do if gaps are found?

Comment: I want to compare 2020-01-01 with 2020-01-02 , there will be 2020-01-02 for sure . Each day files will be created there wont be a missing date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's probably not too terrible to do:

```
for base in example polar; do
    if ! diff ${base}-$today.txt ${base}-$yesteday.txt; then    
        python script.py ${base}-$today.txt
    fi
done
```

That should be fairly maintainable, and you can write `list='example polar ...'` ... `for base in $list`, or `list=$( cmd to dynamically generate names)`, or use an array.  There's a lot of flexibility.  For example, if you don't want to maintain the list of files, you could do:

```
for file in *-${today}.txt; do 
    base="${file%-${today}.txt}"
    if ! diff "${base}-$today.txt" "${base}-$yesteday.txt"; then    
        python script.py "${base}-$today.txt"
    fi
done
```

Note that I've removed the excess verbosity.  Succeed quietly, fail loudly.

Comment: Compact solution